# MNIST Digit dataset requires login

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, mnist

I want to download the MNIST handwritten digit data from the offical site: https://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

But it wants me to enter a username and a password. **How can I download the data? Does anybody know the credentials or any backup?**

Thank you.

Comment: The link is not working when hyperlinked. I will suggest to google  MNIST dataset and access link from the results it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the link from the previous answer doesn't work anymore, you can download the dataset from here now:

https://github.com/MrHeadbang/machineLearning/blob/main/mnist.zip

Answer (score 4):

You can download it from here :
Just click on it, and the download will automatically started
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How can I open this .npz file?

Comment: @ShimiShimson You just need to load it via tensorflow
like : mnist = tf.keras.dataset.load_data()
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data

Answer (score 1):

The dataset can be downloaded from here:
https://deepai.org/dataset/mnist

Additionally, Pytorch allows you to download it with:

```
dataset = datasets.MNIST('../data', train=True, download=True,
                   transform=transform)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking for this for hours. You saved me so much time :)

Comment: Thatl link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: this link doesn't work anymore